# ansible - "when" condition not working with logical "AND" operator

Tags: yaml, jinja2, ansible

I am trying to write ansible playbooks for dev and test env provisioning for a django app. However there seems to be a problem in using when conditional in the ansible tasks.

In below code the Task 2 is executed when ever the Task 1 is changed. It doesn't check for the second condition.

```
- name: Task 1
  become: yes
  command: docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py migrate chdir="{{ server_code_path }}"
  when: perform_migration
  register: django_migration_result
  changed_when: "'No migrations to apply.' not in django_migration_result.stdout"
  tags:
    - start_service
    - django_manage

- name: Task 2 # Django Create Super user on 1st migration
  become: yes
  command: docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py loaddata create_super_user_data.yaml chdir="{{ server_code_path }}"
  when: django_migration_result|changed and ("'Applying auth.0001_initial... OK' in django_migration_result.stdout")
  ignore_errors: yes
  tags:
    - start_service
    - django_manage
```

Task 2 is run whenever Task1 is changed without evaluating second conditional

```
"'Applying auth.0001_initial... OK' in django_migration_result.stdout"
```

When I try without `django_migration_result|changed` it is working as intended.

```
- name: Task 2 # Django Create Super user on 1st migration
  become: yes
  command: docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py loaddata create_super_user_data.yaml chdir="{{ server_code_path }}"
  when: "'Applying auth.0001_initial... OK' in django_migration_result.stdout"
```

The above is working as intended. I tried replacing it with boolean var, even still no luck.

Ansible version: 2.0.0.1

Any ideas, kindly help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second condition appears to be a string. I mean the whole condition. A string always is true.

```
"'Applying auth.0001_initial... OK' in django_migration_result.stdout"
```

In your last code block, the whole condition is in quotes. That would be a string on the yaml level and the reason why it then works.

This:

```
key: value
```

is the same as:

```
key: "value"
```

Writing your condition like this should do the trick:

```
when: django_migration_result|changed and ('Applying auth.0001_initial... OK' in django_migration_result.stdout)
```

Or even better:

```
when:
  - django_migration_result | changed
  - 'Applying auth.0001_initial... OK' in django_migration_result.stdout
```

Comment: that worked like a charm, you saved my day. however I want to point out that second method works only when enclosing `- 'Applying auth.0001_initial... OK' in django_migration_result.stdout` within brackets.
So it should be: ` - ( 'Applying auth.0001_initial... OK' in django_migration_result.stdout)`

Comment: True. Ansible expects the whole thing to be quoted if it starts with a quote. Forgot about that one. :)

Comment: I find Ansible's syntax utterly bewildering like this. In some places you have to quote and use escapes, e.g. `"{{ variable|int }}"`. In other places, you can write a condition bare. In some of those places it seems like the quoted-and-escaped form doesn't work either...